# What causes pinkish hue to some skins?

Tags: skin

I know it is caused either by blood vessels beneath skin , or some pigment called "pheomelanin" . But what is it in fact?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in hemoglobin, which is responsible for the transportation of oxygen throughout our bodies. It is the protein found in red blood cells, and thus it has a reddish hue to it. When an organism has lightly pigmented skin, the oxygenated hemoglobin causes the pinkish hue that you are describing.

Comment: then , this happens if the skin is not much pigmented, and if there are much melanin pigments , the hemoglobins in blood cant be visible, isn't it ?

Comment: Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please [edit] to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.